# Can't discover service created with PyBluez

Tags: python, bluetooth, visibility

I'm trying to make a simple bluetooth service on Python using PyBluez and looks like it works, but I can't find that service with neither my phone, nor with PyBluez itself. I'm able to discovery my phone bluetooth when I do search with PyBluez, but not the server created with PyBluez. What's wrong with the code bellow?

```
import bluetooth

server_sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )

port = 0 # automatically choose port
server_sock.bind(("",port))
server_sock.listen(1)

uuid = "1e0ca4ea-299d-4335-93eb-27fcfe7fa848"
bluetooth.advertise_service( server_sock, "FooBar Service", uuid )

client_sock,address = server_sock.accept()
print "Accepted connection from ",address

data = client_sock.recv(1024)
print "received [%s]" % data

client_sock.close()
server_sock.close()
```

I'm enabling service visibility with `hciconfig hci0 piscan`, so my phone is able to find a bluetooth device with name of my PC, but not the service I've created (I mean `FooBar Service`).
Also I can't find my service using `sdptool browse` command.

Do I misunderstand something? How to connect to the service I've created?

**update**

Here is the below mentioned code result executed on my Windows 7 PC with D-Link Bluetooth adapter.

[image]

**update**

Finally it worked when I run client from another computer. It doesn't work locally, but why I can't discover this service from any device? Is there anything special I should do to make it behave like a normal Bluetooth service?

Answer (score 5):

First of all your code it's not a **service** it's a **Server** that uses uses RFCOMM sockets.

It's very similar to the use of python socket programming (you can read more [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_networking.htm))

I'll use a simple example from the PyBluez [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/pybluez/wiki/Documentation):

**Server part:**

```
from bluetooth import *

server_sock=BluetoothSocket( RFCOMM )
server_sock.bind(("",PORT_ANY))
server_sock.listen(1)

port = server_sock.getsockname()[1]

uuid = "94f39d29-7d6d-437d-973b-fba39e49d4ee"

advertise_service( server_sock, "SampleServer",
                   service_id = uuid,
                   service_classes = [ uuid, SERIAL_PORT_CLASS ],
                   profiles = [ SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE ])

print("Waiting for connection on RFCOMM channel %d" % port)

client_sock, client_info = server_sock.accept()

print("Accepted connection from ", client_info)

#this part will try to get something form the client
# you are missing this part - please see it's an endlees loop!!
try:
    while True:
        data = client_sock.recv(1024)
        if len(data) == 0: break
        print("received [%s]" % data)

# raise an exception if there was any error
except IOError:
    pass

print("disconnected")

client_sock.close()
server_sock.close()
```

**Client Part** (copy paste for the docs):

```
from bluetooth import *
import sys

if sys.version < '3':
    input = raw_input

addr = None

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("no device specified.  Searching all nearby bluetooth devices for")
    print("the SampleServer service")
else:
    addr = sys.argv[1]
    print("Searching for SampleServer on %s" % addr)

# search for the SampleServer service
uuid = "94f39d29-7d6d-437d-973b-fba39e49d4ee"
service_matches = find_service( uuid = uuid, address = addr )

if len(service_matches) == 0:
    print("couldn't find the SampleServer service =(")
    sys.exit(0)

first_match = service_matches[0]
port = first_match["port"]
name = first_match["name"]
host = first_match["host"]

print("connecting to \"%s\" on %s" % (name, host))

# Create the client socket
sock=BluetoothSocket( RFCOMM )
sock.connect((host, port))

print("connected.  type stuff")
while True:
    data = input()
    if len(data) == 0: break
    sock.send(data)

sock.close()
```

**Your Problem:**

I can't see any client code, you need to create a client and to connect the server.

You need to change it just like above, run the Server and then the Client.

Then you will see at the server the client connection.

Another useful link is [here](http://homepages.ius.edu/RWISMAN/C490/html/PythonandBluetooth.htm) it really helped me.

**Edit:**

Since my current desktop doesn't have BT it's a bit tricky.

There's a great example for BlueZ server-client [here](http://kevindoran1.blogspot.co.il/2013/04/bluetooth-programming-with-python-3.html) at the bottom.

It is using MAC address:

**Server Code:** change the `hostMACAddress` param - it's your adapter mac address

**Client Code:** change `serverMACAddress` to what you wrote at 'hostMACAddress'

Comment: I run this server. The problem is that I can't see any bluetooth services named `SampleServer` on my phone. Do I misunderstand something? Also the code you posted gives error `couldn't find the SampleServer service =(`

Comment: @axe i don't have BT on my current PC but those examples worked for me few months ago, I've edited my post, lets try using MAC ADDRESS this code also worked, please let me know it it helped.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for late answer, this task was deferred. Now I returned to it. Just tried once again. Connected Bluetooth module to my machine and started server on my windows PC. Nothing, neither sample client code above, nor my phone or any other device is able to see this service.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by changing the `address` argument of `bluetooth.find_service` to `localhost`. This is a special case that allows you to search for local SDP, https://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/x290.html.